# Crear una tabla mediante DOM con celdas 2x2 - Funciones DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estoy realizando una tabla de 4 casillas, 2x2, y he creado los elementos mediante DOM, sólo se puede utilizar funciones DOM.

¿Por qué no me genera la tabla?

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <title>Animales!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/estilo.css"/>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/animales.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Javascript/DOM:**

```
/*Registro un evento para cuando termine de cargarse el documento se cargen los eventos necesarios.*/
window.onload = crearTabla();

/*Exclusivamente con DOM, crear una tabla 2x2 (4 elementos-casillas).*/
function crearTabla() {
    //Obtener la referencia del elemento body.
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>.
    var tabla = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    //Crea las celdas.
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        //Crea las hileras de la tabla.
        var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j=0; j<2; j++) {
            var celda = document.createElement("td");
            var textoCelda = document.createTextNode("Hilera "+i+", Columna "+j);
            celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
            hilera.appendChild(celda);
        }
        //Agrega la hilera al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody).
        tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
    }

    //Posiciona el <tbody> debajo del elemento <table>.
    tabla.appendChild(tblBody);
    //appends <table> into <body>.
    body.appendChild(tabla);
    //Modifica el atributo "border" de la tabla y lo fija a "2";
    tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

Comment: Hola @omaza1990. Por favor intentemos prestar atención a la hora de crear nuevas etiquetas. En especial con **meta-etiquetas** como `[tabla]` que no definen en absoluto a la pregunta. Más información en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas ejecutando la funcion `crearTabla` y se los estas asignando a la propiedad `onload` de `window` : `window.onload = crearTabla();`.

Deberias asignarle la funcion y no el resultado: `window.onload = crearTabla;`